# Deploy Angular 6 in hosting name.com error routing url

Tags: angular

I have loaded my application made with angular 6 and cli in a conventional hosting of name.com

For this I have followed the following steps:

- ng build --prod
- This generates me the `dist` folder
- In the hosting in the root folder `public_html` I created a subfolder
      called `/test1` and there I put all the contents of the dist folder

Apparently everything works fine except for a couple of things: For example on the routes everything ok but when I copy and paste the url or update the page where I am at that moment I get the following error:

> Not Found.
>
> The requested URL /section/subsection was not found on this
>   server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

So when I run `http://example.com/test1` it works fine but when I type `http://example.com/test1/mysection` it does not work anymore. But if I navigate within the site through the main menu it works fine.

That could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

If you're deploying to a sub-folder, then you need to specify both --deploy-url and --base-href options in order for your assets to resolve properly and for routing to work:

```
ng build --prod  --deploy-url /test1/ --base-href /test1/
```